May I say "I can't have more" to mean "I've had enough","I can not tolerate anymore"?
May I say "I can't have more" to mean "I've had enough","I can not tolerate anymore" ?
Like: The weather here is so wet, I can't have more.

Yes, it's okay.

It's grammatical, but there are few situations where using this turn of phrase wouldn't make one sound like a beginner in English as a foreign language.

Never tell a generous cook I'm on a diet, but "I'm stuffed" "Couldn't fit more if I tried," or "I am ready to waddle out of here. Please!"

A native speaker would say "I can't have any more", but even that would sound odd, as though someone is not allowing you to have any more. Talking about something like bad weather, you would say "I can't take any more". (Take in this context means endure.)

And @Ciao, your last question and understanding is correct. Few situations where this wouldn't... is effectively a double negative construction, and therefore harder to understand. What Edwin meant was that in most situations using the original phrase would make you sound like a beginner.

You mean you don't want more, or you're physically or mentally unable to take any more?

When we've reached our limit,
if it's weather related, we can say:

The weather here is so wet, I can't stand it any more.

if it's food related:

I'm so full I couldn't eat another bite.

if it's about emotional strain:

I'm so mentally exhausted/stressed out I can't bear it any more.
… I can't take it any longer.


+1 Depending on the situation.

And "I can't take any more" works in most such contexts.

I like  “I can't take any more”,  :)
